# multiple taylor diagram error _Error in unit(0.5 * showr, "strwidth", list(right)) : no string supplied for 'strwidth/height' unit

Tags: r, openair

I am using TaylorDiagram to have 4 plots of 4 sites in one panel. However when I run my code it only shows the first plot.

This is my code:
TaylorDiagram(mod.dat_all, obs = "obs", mod = "sim", type = "site")
I have three columns in "mod.dat_all: obs (numeric), sim(numeric), site(character)
I get this error:

**Error in unit(0.5 * showr, "strwidth", list(right)) :
no string supplied for 'strwidth/height' unit**

Anyone came across on this issue before? Are we able to put station'name attached to TaylorDiagram (like what we see in this picture)? thank you! here you see what I got with running the code (up), and what I want to see (down)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My error was that the vector with the names was as a number and had to be as a character. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).